# Does Perl's Safe understand new features?

Tags: perl, opcode

I'm playing with the [Safe](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html) module for inclusion in *[Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org/)*. Versions before v5.16 (the earliest supported version) doesn't seem to understand new keywords. Am I missing something?

### say works with v5.16 and later

```
use v5.10;

use Safe;

say "Running $0 under $^V with Safe ", Safe->VERSION;

my $compartment = Safe->new;
$compartment->permit( ':base_io', ':load' );

my $code =<<"CODE";
use v5.10;
say "Hello Safe!";
CODE

$compartment->reval( $code ) or do {
        my $error = $@;
        warn "Safe compartment error! $@";
        };
```

This code runs as I expect under v5.18 and v5.16, the two [officially supported versions of Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html):

```
% perl5.18.0 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.18.0 with Safe 2.35
Hello Safe!

% perl5.16.3 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.16.3 with Safe 2.35
Hello Safe!
```

It doesn't work prior to v5.16 since it doesn't think the [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) keyword is valid:

```
% perl5.14.4 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.14.4 with Safe 2.35
String found where operator expected at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""
    (Do you need to predeclare say?)
Safe compartment error! syntax error at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""

% perl5.12.3 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.12.3 with Safe 2.35
String found where operator expected at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""
    (Do you need to predeclare say?)
Safe compartment error! syntax error at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""

% perl5.10.1 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.10.1 with Safe 2.35
String found where operator expected at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""
    (Do you need to predeclare say?)
Safe compartment error! syntax error at (eval 5) line 2, near "say "Hello Safe!""
```

### state doesn't work but breaks differently

With [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) it's different.

```
use v5.10;

use Safe;

say "Running $0 under $^V with Safe ", Safe->VERSION;

my $compartment = Safe->new;
$compartment->permit( ':base_io', ':load' );

my $code =<<'CODE';
use v5.10;
print "Hello Safe!\n";
foo();
sub foo {
    state $n = 0;
    print "n is $n\n";
    }
CODE

$compartment->reval( $code ) or do {
        my $error = $@;
        warn "Safe compartment error! $@";
        };
```

v5.18 and v5.16 think [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) is a syntax error:

```
% perl5.18.0 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.18.0 with Safe 2.35
Hello Safe!
n is 0

% perl5.16.3 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.16.3 with Safe 2.35
Hello Safe!
n is 0
```

Before those versions, I think it's treating `state` as an indirect method:

```
% perl5.14.4 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.14.4 with Safe 2.35
Hello Safe!
Safe compartment error! Can't call method "state" on an undefined value at (eval 5) line 5.
```

### given

`given` has the same problem:

```
use v5.10;

use Safe;

say "Running $0 under $^V with Safe ", Safe->VERSION;

my $compartment = Safe->new;
$compartment->permit( ':base_io', ':load' );

my $code =<<'CODE';
use v5.10;
print "Hello Safe!\n";
my $foo = 'Buster Bean';
given( $foo ) {
    when( /Buster/ ) { print "Buster\n" }
    }
CODE

$compartment->reval( $code ) or do {
        my $error = $@;
        warn "Safe compartment error! $@";
        };
```

It works just fine in v5.16 and v5.18:

```
% perl5.18.0 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.18.0 with Safe 2.35
given is experimental at (eval 5) line 4.
when is experimental at (eval 5) line 5.
Hello Safe!
Buster
```

But breaks in earlier versions:

```
% perl5.14.4 safe.pl
Running safe.pl under v5.14.4 with Safe 2.35
Safe compartment error! syntax error at (eval 5) line 4, near ") {"
```

Comment: I think the problem is actually in Opcode, but that's a maze.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to use bisecting tool to check when certain piece of code started working. One is included, if you clone entire Perl repository. This allows to check when it started to work.

```
~/perl> Porting/bisect.pl --expect-fail --start=v5.14.0 --end=v5.16.3 -e '
        use v5.10;

        use Safe;

        say "Running $0 under $^V with Safe ", Safe->VERSION;

        my $compartment = Safe->new;
        $compartment->permit( ":base_io", ":load" );

        my $code =<<"CODE";
        use v5.10;
        say "Hello Safe!";
        CODE

        $compartment->reval( $code ) or do {
                my $error = $@;
                warn "Safe compartment error! $@";
                exit 1;
                };
        '
```

After doing that, you get the result.

```
7d69d4a61be1619f90910462eac42234c874712e is the first bad commit
commit 7d69d4a61be1619f90910462eac42234c874712e
Author: Father Chrysostomos <sprout@cpan.org>
Date:   Thu Dec 15 16:26:16 2011 -0800

    Disable $[ under 5.16

    This adds the array_base feature to feature.pm

    Perl_feature_is_enabled has been modified to use PL_curcop, rather
    than PL_hintgv, so it can work with run-time hints as well.
    (PL_curcop holds the current state op at run time, and &PL_compiling
    at compile time, so it works for both.)  The hints in $^H are not
    stored in the same place at compile time and run time, so the FEATURE_IS_ENABLED macro has been modified to check first whether
    PL_curop == &PL_compiling.

    Since array_base is on by default with no hint for it in %^H, it is
    a ‘negative’ feature, whose entry in %^H turns it off.  feature.pm
    has been modified to support such negative features.  The new FEATURE_IS_ENABLED_d can check whether such default features
    are enabled.

    This does make things less efficient, as every version declaration
    now loads feature.pm to disable all features (including turning off
    array_base, which entails adding an entry to %^H) before loading the
    new bundle.  I have plans to make this more efficient.

:100644 100644 e96e6608641a33838158a54cb0ac2402c716e848 3b81d3fc286480be3512864b43f3c9230fd1c376 M      embed.fnc
:040000 040000 7f9483dd9d2f290810866ad40810461398385515 e1d43bd8aa24bec1d6b5f80a1f36f6787fb70d32 M      ext
:100644 100644 2af41a87c417a2afded5c9f55bd0a69bcf71db80 37a1bd9510eb5064d052fb00b68a0e7eec3df716 M      gv.c
:040000 040000 9d82bf63a49734aec1e01c5da6362c3dec7e1a22 2b12bd8c206ae14fc819fbb781cdb2b09c1a9c95 M      lib
:100644 100644 c55ca63a5819c32c747279ddcc698653dc8eca6f 3432dfe5c4c7b568712a9f0f31177695528892e4 M      mg.c
:100644 100644 313087d34a4135e1854b4f00ab58b71d687a32e1 812ece2bb1757489865e36dec0ceeaa8d6c86168 M      op.c
:100644 100644 e203dfe1941e7c3e13cdf6b68e509339258229bf ef3d4efec6604738d6beded3ff16d9a1ab73c465 M      perl.h
:100644 100644 92befdac8afebe578740e84ca24ca46a091b072e eec052f413638d1efba00c81f423a68d1a4f984e M      proto.h
:040000 040000 9deb7ece55f230bcf0e0bb83a5e1646e05770db2 d425283f05fb825181a2b3836ff3ce2570821500 M      t
:100644 100644 2c29c582e2a1c2ba6aeefe56368a383785b27830 2f395d458da5941b49552d85bbf52b1070b5b32e M      toke.c
bisect run success
That took 1921 seconds
```

The problem is that it was an accidentally fixed bug. If you take a look at [diff for toke.c](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blobdiff/b22bbcf0786b5b4b9edfde241ba29141bb99f219..7d69d4a61be1619f90910462eac42234c874712e:/toke.c), you can notice that the old version took features from `PL_hintgv`, but the new version uses `PL_curcop`. The difference between these is that `PL_hintgv` contains compile time unit settings. `PL_curcop` however, contains current settings. While being in `Safe`, `use feature` saves to wrong place.

The problem is that `PL_hintgv` checks current compilation unit. When dealing with `Safe`, it's meaningless empty hash, because of the hacking the module does to work. `PL_curcop` however checks current scope - so it works well with `Safe`.

Now for workarounds. One exists, but it involves specifying settings by using `eval`. As `eval` sets compilation unit, you can use it to specify settings you want. It won't let user change the settings, but will let provide you some settings for evaluated code.

For example, if you change `$compartment->reval( $code )` with `eval '$compartment->reval( $code )'` in your code, it will start working, as `eval` made a new compilation unit, and your code has `use v5.10;` in heading (`eval` copies `use v5.10` from it). It's an awful hack nevertheless …